# Why aren't multiple-item checkboxes showing in my library's view?

Tags: 2010, document-library, view, library, multi-select

The column containing checkboxes allowing users to select multiple documents isn't visible on one of my list views. I have the value for *Document Library Settings ▶ Edit View ▶ Tabular View* set to "Allow individual item checkboxes", but no dice. This isn't affecting any other views of this library.

Answer (score 2):

I found a resolution on the [Sharepoint forum at technet](http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/51052ca4-8a6f-4c69-8361-2b33f6781b5c/after-upgrade-of-sites-to-sharepoint-2010-im-missing-the-checkbox-column):

> Did you try to set the view to Basic style.. then reset them back to "Default" ?

My view was already set to "Basic", so I set it to "Default", and now the column with the checkboxes is back.

Cheers~